# how to handle returned data from php script

Tags: android

my php script returns this string to my android app:

```
[{"id":"61","device":"a914a24d2352646","lat":"59.864650963824815","lng":"18.150743767619133","comment":"Kkkk","image":null},
    {"id":"62","device":"a914a24d2352646","lat":"59.86462319043523","lng":"18.150545619428158","comment":"Jj","image":null}]
```

to return this data I just do an `echo` of the result. In my java code I do like this to receive this data:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_FETCH_ALERT);

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

Now how can I use this string to create a real array out of it so its more simple to use? Or can I do this another way to get some type of array object from my php sctipt?

Comment: use `json` to better pass arrays between environements...

Comment: my php does this to return the value above: `echo json_encode($alerts);`, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is coming in as a JSONArray, so you would create a JSONArray object then loop through it and pull out the JSONObjects.

```
JSONArray jsonArr= new JSONArray(response);
for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.length();i++){
JSONObject json=jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
//Do whatever you want with that item's data via json.getString('key')
// or json.getInt('key) etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create a Java class, which matches the original class/array you encoded to JSON, such as:

```
public class Obj{
    private long id = 0;
    private String device = "";
    .... etc
}
```

Then, use Gson (or JSON, whichever you prefer), to convert that returned string into your object, for example:

```
 Obj o = new Gson().fromJson(YOURSTRING, Obj.class);
```

Then you can access your object as normal. Obviously you'd have to amend for arrays, but you should get the idea :) Hope this helps!